# Handling a Redirecting Auto Download Link Python

Tags: python, csv, urllib

I have a URL which upon loading in, will automatically download a CSV to your machine.

I am trying to do this automatically in python and control what the downloaded file is named. Here is my current code:

```
import os
import sys
import urllib.request
URL= https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fbasketballmonster.com%2FDaily.aspx%3Fv%3D2%26exportcsv%3DXnZZUZaDa0E296JhVEGWbs8HRGOXsEkeJKs2towTT%2Fw%3D&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHYm9T_QIZvEJ8qIKfyXQuZb4HPVA
response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
URL2 = response.geturl()
urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL2, "file2.csv")
```

For the URL:
https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fbasketballmonster.com%2FDaily.aspx%3Fv%3D2%26exportcsv%3DXnZZUZaDa0E296JhVEGWbs8HRGOXsEkeJKs2towTT%2Fw%3D&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHYm9T_QIZvEJ8qIKfyXQuZb4HPVA

(clicking that downloads a CSV to disk)

However, the CSV downloaded has this html markup instead of being the actual data

Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: Why not just download the target link directly, instead of going through Google?

Comment: eitherway, I get the redirected url.. so I still need to figure out how to download the link